# Trace of Cyclic Permutation of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm working with a symmetric matrix and just want to convince myself that, in this specific case, I can say that the trace of this matrix is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues.

Wikipedia says that the trace of any set of matrix products is invariant under cyclic permutation, but the goes on a few lines down to say

> Arbitrary permutations are not allowed: in general,
>
> $$Tr(ABC) \not = Tr(ACB)$$

This is a little confusing since this exact example is actually a
cyclic permutation ($C$ and $B$ are cycled while $A$ is held fixed).

I just want to clarify whether or not this is a small snafu, or I am totally misunderstanding the details here. I want to use this theorem to say that $Tr(A) = Tr(PDP^{-1}) = Tr(D) =\sum \lambda_i$, and then march happily on my way to try applying this to [Principle Component Analysis](http://www.math.union.edu/~jaureguj/PCA.pdf).

Comment: No, you are making an error, ACB is a transposition of ABC, not a 3-cycle.

Comment: "Cyclic permutation" is the wrong word to use here.  What is true is
that $\text{Tr}(A_1 \ldots A_n) = \text{Tr}(A_k A_{k+1}\ldots A_n A_1 \ldots A_{k-1})$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you, that is what I suspected.

Comment: @JeanMarie Hi, yes I know that's not a 3-cycle. It's a 2-cycle, which still qualifies as a cyclic permutation: "a permutation of the elements of some set $X$ which maps the elements of some subset $S$ of $X$ to each other in a cyclic fashion, while fixing (that is, mapping to themselves) all other elements of $X$". In this case $A$ is mapped to itself and the subset that is cycled contains $B$ and $C$.

Comment: What they consider in the theorem are n-cycles (maximal length).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{Trace}(P(DP^{-1})) = \text{Trace}((DP^{-1}) P) = \text{Trace}(D)$.  Yes, the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to accept because you answered my question in your comment :)